# Create image patches, sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d memory error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I was looking for a way to divide a numpy image into grid like patches.

This task has been answered a couple times.
[Extracting patches of a certain size from the image in python efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878868/extracting-patches-of-a-certain-size-from-the-image-in-python-efficiently)

skleans extract_patches_2d looks exactly right.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html

However, I feel that i'm not understanding the docs.

I have a image, its not particularly large, a few Mb on disk. OpenCV has no trouble with it.

Its dimensions are

```
self.original_image.shape
(1536, 2048, 3)
```

So let's extract it into blocks each 100 X 100. Back of the envelope calculation the number of patches should be something like

(1536 * 2048) / (100*100) = 314

```
patches=extract_patches_2d(self.original_image,(100,100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Debug Probe, prompt 46, line 1
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\image.py", line 374, in extract_patches_2d
    extraction_step=1)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\image.py", line 296, in extract_patches
    patches = as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 48, in as_strided
    array = np.asarray(DummyArray(interface, base=x))
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

This is a numpy memory error. What is causing that?

I get the feeling I don't follow entirely, lets make a tiny image and split that into pretty large sections

```
patches=extract_patches_2d(self.original_image[0:100,0:100],(50,50))
```

That works, but yields thousands of patches

```
len(patches)
2601
```

Not the ~ 4 I'd expect. What am I not understanding about this function? How do people go about getting patches, it seems like a common thing in computer vision.

Python 2.7 on Windows, packages recently installed and up to date

```
Ben@Laptop MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ pip install -U scikit-learn

Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: sklearn also has `extract_patches` (notice no _2d). In this function you can give the step between patches, like `extract_patches(img, (100,100,1), (100,100,1)).squeeze()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function creates  all possible combinations of patches from the given image. 
In your case, the first patch  will span  0:49 pixels row wise and 0: 49 pixels column wise. The second patch from 1:50 row wise and column wise and o on. 
So if you have an image of size (m,n) and wish to extract patches of size (a,b) , then (m-a)+1 x (n-b+1) maximum possible patches can be extracted .
In your case that is 51x 51 = 2601 patches.. 
If you want to limit the number of patches to be extracted, you can do so by the optional parameter by the `max_ patches` parameter.

Comment: oh! That is radically different. All possible combinations! That is totally not mentioned in the docs! I'm looking to divide into consistent sub-grid, so patches of a given size that comprise the full image, not a window search.

Comment: Specifying `max_patches` means randomly choosing `max_patches` patches from all the combinations of the image.